# Why won't my css file link to my html file?

Tags: html, css

Here is my html code :---------------------------------------------------

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>

<head> 
<title>My webpage </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

</head>

<body>
<h1> My website </h1>

<ul>
<li> Home</li>
<li><a href="page2.html"> page 2</a>  </li>
<li><a href="page3.html"> page 3</a> </li>
</ul>
<h2> This is my homepage</h2>
<p> All of my homepage content</p>
</body>

</html>
```

the background is suppose to go red but doesn't ?

css code from another file:

```
body{
background:#red;

}
```

Comment: `background: red;` remove the hash, hashes are only used for hexadecimal colours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a named colour you do not need to use a hash, hashes are only used for hexadecimal colours.

In order to change the background to red, use the following code:

```
background: red;
```

Or, you can do this (#ff0000 is the hexadecimal code for red):

```
background: #ff0000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Named colors do not need hash sign:

```
body{
background:red;
}
```